# Editar HTML de un documento .html diferente

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Buenas,

estoy intentando hacer un innerHTML a un HTML que no es desde el cual se ha llamado la función. Espero que con el código se entienda mejor.

```
function ventana_cargada() {

       var ventanaPadre = window.opener;
       console.log(ventanaPadre);

       document.getElementById("carga_completada").innerHTML = "<b>Ventana cargada correctamente.</b>";  
}
```

El propósito de esto es que he abierto una nueva ventana con "window.open", y necesito editar el HTML del archivo que eneste caso ha abierto esta ventana. Como veis en el código he consegido obtener la URL del html que quiero editar con "window.opener" pero ahora no se como hacer que la funcion de innerHTML la haga al archivo html padre.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: resuelto: añadiendo la variable "ventanaPadre" delante de la funcion con un punto: ventanaPadre.document.getElementById("carga_completada").innerHTML = "<b>Ventana cargada correctamente.</b>";

Answer (score 0):

no has definido la ventana abierta `var newWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "width=200,height=100");` para saber que es el opener de dicha ventana `var ventanaPadre = newWindow.opener;`

```
<p id='carga_completada'></p>


<button onclick="ventana_cargada()">abrir nueva ventana</button>

<script>
function ventana_cargada() {
    var newWindow = window.open("", "newWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    var ventanaPadre = newWindow.opener;
    newWindow.document.write("<p>Esta es la nueva ventana</p>");
    ventanaPadre.document.getElementById("carga_completada").innerHTML = "<b>ventana padre de la nueva ventana</b>"; 

}
</script>
```

[Ejemplo en try it](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFKCHT6N6OA3)